# How can I change the thickness of the ticks on the right and top axes of a plot?

Tags: plotting, ticks

I want to change the ticks on the right and top axes on a plot like this example:

```
Show[Plot[Exp[-t], {t, 0, 11}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.002]]]]
```

However, only the ticks on the left and bottom axes are changed.

[image]

I played around with curly brackets and no luck. How can I match the ticks on the top and right axes to match the bottom and left axes?

Comment: this is likely a version/OS-related problem; your code gives the expected output in version 13.3.1 (Linux x86  - 64-bit).

Answer (score 1):

```
Plot[Exp[-t], {t, 0, 11},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicksStyle -> {{Automatic, Thickness[0.002]}, {Automatic, Thickness[0.002]}}]
```

[image]

To hide the ticks:

```
Plot[Exp[-t], {t, 0, 11},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem --- this soln gives me a regular plot, whose ticks' thickness have not been changed.